# Tweak next_post_link for it to include thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am using a fork from underscores.io, and there is this code:

```
next_post_link(     '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',     _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link',     'nicosite' ) );
```

Wich prints the next post link,

How Can I use it (or alternatives) to include the post's thumbnail?

-edit-

Right now, I have

```
 next_post_link(     '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',     _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link',     'nicosite' ) );
 $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(300,150) ); 
 echo $nextthumbnail;
```

That it prints out the image, but this way I get outside the `a`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at what `next_post_link` you'll see that it takes a parameter `$link` as the second argument:

[`next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

Your parameter for this currently doesn't include the post thumbnail:

```
_x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link', 'nicosite' )
```

So we need to add it like this:

```
$nextPost = get_next_post(true); // You are aware that this only checks for next posts in the same term, right? 
if(!empty($nextPost) ){ //This is to check if there is a next post
    $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(300,150) );
}else{
    $nextthumbnail ='';
}
next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', $nextthumbnail . _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link', nicosite' ) );
```